# Definition for special rectangles

Tags: functional-analysis, definition, rectangles

I am working my way through the title "Lebesgue Integration on Euclidean Space" by Frank Jones. On page 25 there is a definition for special rectangles. Is there a constraint on these type of rectangles to be parallel to the axis (seems so from the following figure in the book)? If not, what is the definition for these rectangles?

I could not find any good definition online. All I could find is examples like a square. Must a square be parallel to the axis?

Note, the definition for the rectangle is as follows:
$$ I=[a_1,b_1 ]×⋯×[a_n,b_n ]=\{x∈\mathbb R^n |a_i≤x_i≤b_i for 1≤i≤n\}$$

Comment: Do you mean the sides parallel to axis? In general the measure theory use rectangles $[a_1,b_1]x...x[a_n,b_n]$ in R^n, but the theory is consistent if you "rote" this. I suggest you the book by Zygmund about it

Comment: Yes I mean the sides parallel to the axis and yes the definition for the rectangles is $I=[a_1,b_1]x\cdots x[a_n,b_n]$. I am not sure I fully understand the definition then. how do you infer that the sides are parallel to the axis?